# Get call triggering on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I'm using Onchange event, it's working fine. But it also triggering on page load, how can i prevent this on page load?

```
<select onchange="changeVal('step', this.value)">
     <option value="false"> No</option>
     <option value="true">Yes</option>
</select>  

//Function Change Dropdown
function changeVal(step,changeval)
{


var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {



    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","/wp-content/themes/xerius_main/calculator/validations/btnSubmit.php?q="+step+"&q2="+changeval,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Can anyone help to achieve this with this code?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you sure there is no call to it somewhere? https://jsfiddle.net/qmcep0rm/ does not trigger onload

Comment: I checked, there is no other call. Could it be conflict with other function?

Comment: I don't know but that's easy to check, just change the function name to something obscure and reload

Comment: yes checked, now nothing happening.

Comment: Did you change the name of both references of the function name? or just one? If you changed both and nothing happens, check console for errors. There is probably a call to the original function name and now it cannot find it. You could replace the content of the original named function and do an alert(), to see if it is called on load, and test your obscure named function separately

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the function and check the call stack to see where it was called from.